# How to gain root access via a web browser?

Tags: 16.04, root

I've installed open cart on my PC. Now I need to install some plugins or extensions using the url via a browser i.e. localhost/site/something. Unfortunately, when I am trying to access and click on the install button, it is giving me the following error :

```
This installer needs to modify some OpenCart files. Please check write access for following files of your opencart store :
-/admin/controller/module
-/admin/view/template/module
```

How can I access those files with admin privileges via web browser? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag your web server's type - Apache, Nginx, etc. You must give write permissions to the web server's user. You can find the exact locations of these folders by the command: `sudo updatedb; locate /admin/controller/module && locate /admin/view/template/module`. If your web server is Apache, the default user is `www-data`, so you can `chown` of these folders via these commands: `sudo chown -R www-data $(locate admin/controller/module)` and `sudo chown -R www-data $(locate admin/view/template/module)`.

Comment: Just noting that (unless it's got a terminal emulator in a control panel) you can't issue above commands through the web.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the title for your post. Answer to question in title is "you can't". Answer to body depends on OS (which you should specify) - but

You DONT need root access to do this. You need the access that the web server has to write the files - on Linux Apache systems this is typically www-data or https or apache. + but if you are using my modules it could be anything - you need to find this out from your web provider.

There are security risks associated with doing this but you could also use FTP to allow "all users" write perms to the parent directory.

Comment: You can't make the desired changes through a web url.